# Android SecretKey AES and JWK : How to convert

Tags: java, aes, jwk

I have an app what needs to share private AES keys. (they are wrapped).
The server will send  and receive the keys  in JWK format.

For the moment, in android I can generate AES KEY like this :

```
public SecretKey  generate() throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator  = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
        KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameter = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("MyKeyAlias", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
              .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
              .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
              .build();
        keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameter);
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();

    }
```

Is there an easy way to convert SecretKey to JWK format ? and vice-versa

If not, I saw the **getEncoded()** method in **SecretKey** class.
[How to export symmetric encryption key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330494/how-to-export-symmetric-encryption-key)

Maybe I need to create my own class to do the conversion

Thanks

Comment: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwk-generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create my own JWK class.
And I used GSON library to parse / stringify JSON.

**Another solution :**

@jps proposed to use this library
connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwk-generation